# Group key onesignal push notification

Tags: php, android, notifications, onesignal

created a project on one signal.

I can send to php notification on my phone.

The problem comes when it arrives more than one notification. The new notification replaces the previous notification (not yet read ).

How do you get instead say that Android has 2 unread notifications?

I have try write the same `android_group` but the notification never stacked and the newest continue replace the previus.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function sendMessage(){
$content = array(
  "en" => 'text message test'
  );

$fields = array(
  'app_id' => "XXxxxxXX-xxxxXX-XXxxX-Xxxx-XxxxXXx",
  'included_segments' => array('All'),
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
  'headings' => array("en" => "Test message!!"),
  'android_group'  => 'TESTGROUP',
  'android_group_message' => array("en" => "message"),
  'contents' => $content
);

$fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                       'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
?>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android_group` used to enable notification stacking only works for Android apps.

If you are you're web push with Chrome for Android the replacement behavior your seeing is expected and isn't configurable. Same behavior on Chrome for Desktop and Firefox.

Also note `android_group_message` should contain $[notif_count] so the number of unread messages is seen. Example
`array("en" => "You have $[notif_count] new messages")`

Comment: Thank you. I have found a solution. Just save into a database the notification string, check if a device where you want send the notification has been read the previus notification in the database. If a device id have more than one norification to read, just send a new notification with the content of the first and the second. With this method i can send more notifications in one.